# iOS difference between 2 times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, date, epoch

This is the situation here. I have current time in epoch. also I have number of days. I want to find the difference between the 2 to give some past time in epoch format. i.e.

> currentEpochTime - (x days) to give some past time in epoch format.

This is what I have gotten so far -

```
+ (double)currTimeInEpoch
{
    NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
    double ti         = [todayDate timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
    return ti;    
}

+ (NSString *)timeDiff:(double)epoch diff:(double)diffInDays
{
    double past = epoch - (diffInDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    return [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:past] stringValue];
}
```

Is what I am doing correct? Not sure about it. Is there any simpler way to do this ?

Comment: keep in mind that hardcoding the amount of seconds per day will give you an error on some days. I don't exactly remember why or when but there are some days that have either less or more seconds. You should consider using more of Apple's APIs

Comment: so the general approach is correct? what are the "more of apple APIs"? care to point me to them ?

Comment: Using stuff like NSCalander, NSDate and NSDateComponents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's dangerous to go alone. Take this.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.day = -40; // Number of days to subtract
NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
NSTimeInterval newDateInEpochTime = [newDate timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
```

Comment: why the - ? i.e. the negative sign ?

Comment: Because we're subtracting from the current date. A positive number would yield a date that many days in the future.

Comment: dont think this is working. check this - `currEpoch:1323198037810.851 epochFor2DaysAgo :1323198037810.86`. where `dateComponents.day = 2`. And both are same !!

Comment: I just tried this code with `day` set to 2 and received the following output. `Current date in epoch time: 1323198250996.670898 | 
New date in epoch time: 1323371050996.649902`. The code works as expected.

Comment: sorry, lack of sleep has done me. was compiling some other project & expecting the result! It works. Thanks for help...

Comment: You should probably test this in cases around daylight savings time, if you care. If your starting time is close to midnight, you **may** get a different day than you expect (I'm not positive).